# Get RGB Color Percentage From Image

Tags: c#, bitmap, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, writablebitmap

How does one get the RGB color percentages from an image in windows app store by using a writable bitmap.

In Windows app I was getting it earlier like this:

```
public static Color getDominantColor(Bitmap bmp)
{

       //Used for tally
       int r = 0;
       int g = 0;
       int b = 0;

     int total = 0;

     for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
     {
          for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
          {
               Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

               r += clr.R;
               g += clr.G;
               b += clr.B;

               total++;
          }
     }

     //Calculate average
     r /= total;
     g /= total;
     b /= total;

     return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
}
```

How can you do this with a writable bitmap in a Metro App?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`BitmapDecoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.aspx) class. It should have everything you need.

Basically, get the pixel data asynchronously, then use it as you have. Just be warned that sometimes the pixel data is saved in 16-bit chunks (two bytes each), so you'll have to do a quick Linq call on the byte array to turn it into a usable pixel array.